# How do I make form in Django using rows of one model, to make entries on another model?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm new to Django frameworks. I'm building site for some kind of activities progress report.

There is a set of predefined Activities consisting of 5 Activities, but can be changed (add/delete). 
This set is used by all Departments. 
Each Department will make entries of their progress report each month, number of works done, on each of these activities.

The models are :

```
class Department(models.Model):
    dept_id = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
    dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

# this one is extending the Django user model
class UserDept(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_dept = models.ForeignKey(Department)

class Month(models.Model):
    month_id = models.SmallIntegerField()
    month_name = models.CharField(max_length=9)

# defining the activities, is_active field to disable particular activities
class Activities(models.Model):
    actv_id = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=True)
    actv_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    works_target = models.SmallIntegerField()
    year = models.SmallIntegerField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

# entries of work done for each activities of each month, by each department
class ProgressReport(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    month = models.ForeignKey(Month)
    activities = models.ForeignKey(Activities)
    work_done = models.IntegerField()
    modifydate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

My problem is, I need the form to submit 5 activities at once, in one click of submit button, and will make entry into the ProgressReport model.

The form should looks like ( basically like Excel Sheet) :

(The activities take dynamically from Activities model) |  (dotted line is the form text field for the entry of work_done)

1. activity1  :   ....
2. activity2  :   ....
3. activity3  :   ....
4. activity4  :   ....
5. activity5  :   ....

(Submit Button)

How do I make the activities from the activities model become the formfield, with activity name as label, and also write  the department (already in one session variable) and month value to the database?

Comment: Have you checked? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/

Comment: Yes, I've read that, but maybe I need more specific guidance, as I'm still new with Django. I mean, as I understand, django model form will be tied with certain model. I'm still confused at how I can take the activities rows from activities models, and use it to make form that tied to the progress_report model

Comment: the thing you are looking for is called `FormSet`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: thanks. I got that now.